# Pandas error while finding unique values in a column with name changed

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the Titanic survival dataset. After I read the data, I change one of the column names and then try to work with it. The changed column name, however, is reflected in the column names but not available for a specific purpose as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
titanic = pd.read_excel("titanic.xls", "titanic")
print(titanic.columns.values)
```

which gives me:

```
['pclass' 'survived' 'name' 'sex' 'age' 'sibsp' 'parch' 'ticket' 'fare'
 'cabin' 'embarked' 'boat' 'body' 'home.dest']
```

Now, I change one of the column names:

```
titanic.columns.values[-1] = 'home'
print(titanic.columns.values)
```

where the output reflects the changed name:

```
['pclass' 'survived' 'name' 'sex' 'age' 'sibsp' 'parch' 'ticket' 'fare'
 'cabin' 'embarked' 'boat' 'body' 'home']
```

Now, if I try to print unique values from the columns,

```
print(pd.unique(titanic.name))
```

I get the desired output:

```
['Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton' ... ]
```

but here,

```
print(pd.unique(titanic.home))
```

I get,

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'home'
```

Comment: you're running into a chained assignment issue. see : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you. You can add that as an answer if you like. It was producing a copy and not working on the original frame.

Comment: added an answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a chained assignment issue. When you assign a value to the columns list, it's operating on a copy of the dataframe, and not on the dataframe itself.

The fix is described in [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for Pandas, and usually requires saving the copy of the dataframe when you make changes to it.

Using the suggested method, this is how it works:

```
newCols = titanic.columns.values
newCols[-1] = 'home'
titanic.columns = newCols
```

A copy of the names is first saved, edited and then directly assigned to the columns.